# Mock response data with serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework

The docs give the following as a mock example:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          cors: true
          method: get
          integration: mock
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
          response:
            template: $input.path('$')
            statusCodes:
              201:
                pattern: ''
```

This does create a mock response...except it's empty.

How can I actually return data here?  I've tried adding `application/json: {...}` to `template`, but that doesn't work, I've tried adding a body under `statusCodes` but no luck there either.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this...how can I return an actual body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the value of `response.template`.  However, this isn't done using an `application/json` key like `request` is, you just set `template` directly.

**Return a string `foo`**

```
response:
  template: "foo"
    statusCodes:
      201:
      pattern: ''
```

**Return JSON**

```
response:
  template: ${file(foo.txt)}
    statusCodes:
      201:
      pattern: ''


# Where foo.txt contains regular JSON

{
  "foo":"bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to return mock response data...

```
functions:

  helloworld:
    handler: api/handler.mock
    events:
      - http:
          path: ''
          method: get
          integration: mock
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'          
          response:
            template: '{"code": 200,"message": "Helloworld!"}'
            statusCodes:
              200:
                body: '{"code": 200,"message": "Helloworld!"}'
```