# How to implement redirect (301 code) mock in serverless framework config (for AWS) without lambda

Tags: serverless-framework

I'd like that the root path of my API redirect (301) to completely another site with docs. So I have a lambda at e.g `/function1` path and the `/` should return code 301 with another location. And I'd like to do it without another lambda.

This is exactly what is [described here](https://alestic.com/2015/11/amazon-api-gateway-aws-cli-redirect/), but via aws command line tool. I tried this approach - it works perfectly, but I'd like to configure such API gateway mock via serverless framework config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the series of CLI commands you linked to can be reproduced in CloudFormation, which can then be dropped into the `Resources` section of your *Serverless* template.

In this example, a `GET` to `/function1` will invoke a lambda function, while a `GET` to `/` will return a 301 to a well-known search engine.

```
service: sls-301-mock

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: function1
          method: get

resources:
  Resources:
    Method:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        HttpMethod: GET
        ResourceId: 
          !GetAtt ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        MethodResponses:
          - ResponseModels: {"application/json":"Empty"}
            StatusCode: 301
            ResponseParameters: 
              "method.response.header.Location": true
        Integration:
          Type: MOCK
          RequestTemplates:
            "application/json": "{\n \"statusCode\": 301\n}"         
          IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 301
              ResponseParameters:
                "method.response.header.Location": "'https://google.com'"
```

Tested with:

```
Framework Core: 1.62.0
Plugin: 3.3.0
SDK: 2.3.0
Components Core: 1.1.2
Components CLI: 1.4.0
```

**Notes**

`ApiGatewayRestApi` is, by convention, the logical name of the API Gateway Stage resource created by *Serverless* on account of the `http` event.

**Relevant CloudFormation documentation**

[ApiGateway::Method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html)

[ApiGateway::Method Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html)

---

EDIT

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59790027/2999566) is not as verbose, and uses an `http` event instead of the `Resources` section.  I haven't tested it, but it may also work for you.

Comment: Resolved the issue with the approach posted below (double event for one function). But your option looks more universal so probably more preferable. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achieve it with referring one function twice. But see also reply of Mike Patrick - looks more universal

```
    ...
    events:
      - http:
          path: main/root/to/the/function
          method: get
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
          integration: mock
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{"statusCode": 301}'
          response:
            template: redirect
            headers:
              Location: "'my-redirect-url-note-the-quotes-they-are-important'"
            statusCodes:
              301:
                pattern: ''
```